# Using XeTeXlinebreaklocale for non space delimited languages, locales?

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, cjk

I am currently using xeCJK for Chinese/Japanese/Korean languages. Using Polyglossia for Thai, with the line break setting:

```
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th"
```

I've seen several people discuss the use of the line break locale command, mostly referencing Thai and Myanmar, and specific codes for each. What I have yet to find however is a list of these locales to use with them. For example the two character code 'th' meaning Thai. Where does this come from?

I am currently trying to handle Khmer in my document, but it is just running off of the page. Rather than simply get "Use XX for the locale" I'd rather be taught to fish instead and know where to get the proper codes.

Comment: After complaining to my wife, she investigated standards and practices which ended up being where these come from. I was searching Xetex specific documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's apparently the [ISO 639-1 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) that is used. For Khmer the two-letter code is "km" (official source: [Language codes - ISO 639](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/language_codes.htm)).