# Where to find documentation for XeTeX's line breaking behavior?

Tags: xetex, line-breaking

I am trying to find out more about how XeTeX implements line breaking for different languages using `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale`. From the [XeTeX reference guide](https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/info/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf):

> `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale`⟨*Locale ID*⟩:
>   Defines how to break lines for multilingual text.

That's all the information I could find about it, leaving me with several questions:

1. What are acceptable values for ⟨*Locale ID*⟩? In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213146/using-xetexlinebreaklocale-for-non-space-delimited-languages-locales) the OP arrives at the conclusion that ISO 639-1 language codes are used, but where can I find out which one of these are actually implemented and lead to changes in XeTeX's behavior?
2. Where in my TeX Live system would I find a file containing the line breaking information specific to each locale? It seems like it must be baked in into XeTeX the engine directly as it works even if I only load what `xetex.ini` loads, which as far as I can see does not include or `\input` any file containing such information.
3. Is there any way to find documentation on how exactly the line breaking algorithm changes when a `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` command is issued?

Now let me add that I do know that certain XeLaTeX packages handle multilingual line breaking for me, but this is not what I am looking for; I am interested in getting to know what XeTeX does exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well in `xetex.web` you end up here

```
procedure do_locale_linebreaks(s: integer; len: integer);
var
  offs, prevOffs, i: integer;
  use_penalty, use_skip: boolean;
begin
  if (XeTeX_linebreak_locale = 0) or (len = 1) then begin
    link(tail):=new_native_word_node(main_f, len);
    tail:=link(tail);
    for i:=0 to len - 1 do
      set_native_char(tail, i, native_text[s + i]);
    set_native_metrics(tail, XeTeX_use_glyph_metrics);
  end else begin
    use_skip:=XeTeX_linebreak_skip <> zero_glue;
    use_penalty:=XeTeX_linebreak_penalty <> 0 or not use_skip;
    linebreak_start(main_f, XeTeX_linebreak_locale, native_text + s, len);
    offs:=0;
    repeat
      prevOffs:=offs;
      offs:=linebreak_next;
      if offs > 0 then begin
        if prevOffs <> 0 then begin
          if use_penalty then
            tail_append(new_penalty(XeTeX_linebreak_penalty));
          if use_skip then
            tail_append(new_param_glue(XeTeX_linebreak_skip_code));
        end;
        link(tail):=new_native_word_node(main_f, offs - prevOffs);
        tail:=link(tail);
        for i:=prevOffs to offs - 1 do
          set_native_char(tail, i - prevOffs, native_text[s + i]);
        set_native_metrics(tail, XeTeX_use_glyph_metrics);
      end;
    until offs < 0;
  end
end;
```

so the locale ends up being passed to

`linebreak_start(main_f, XeTeX_linebreak_locale, native_text + s, len);`

As Marcel points out in comments below this function is defined in `xetex_ext.c`  where it is called `linebreakstart` (general C-web name mapping rules)

```
linebreakstart(int f, integer localeStrNum, uint16_t* text, integer textLength)
...
```

Which in turn basically calls the ICU library `ubrk_open` function which implements the locale-specific linebreaking from
  [UAX #14](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/) with the locale data available in the [ICU tree](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/tree/master/icu4c/source/data/brkitr). Actual changes occur for all locales for which the file there contains a line:process line like [zh](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/master/icu4c/source/data/brkitr/zh.txt)

see also

http://userguide.icu-project.org/boundaryanalysis

Comment: You are right, `linebreak_start` is defined (as `linebreakstart`) in `XeTeX_ext.c` and mostly just calls ICU's ubrk_open. It implements [UAX #14](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/) with the locale data available [in the ICU tree](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/tree/master/icu4c/source/data/brkitr) Actual changes occur for all locales for which the file there contains a `line:process` line like [zh](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/blob/master/icu4c/source/data/brkitr/zh.txt)

Comment: ah thanks, I lost the `_` name mangling in going between web and C:-)

Comment: when is `(XeTeX_linebreak_locale = 0) or (len = 1)` actually true?

Comment: @wave er I think the first just if you have not used `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` and the second if it's a one letter word, but I'd have to try to read (and understand:-)  more of the web sources than I can do at the present time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle interestingly, some Japanese text is not broken into lines at all, creating very overfull hboxes, when I don't specify a `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` (only after a newline, probably breaking at the space token inserted), but it does look normal if I set `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale 0` (or to any value really).

Comment: @wave begin
  scan_file_name; {scan a filename-like arg for the locale name}
  if length(cur_name) = 0 then XeTeX_linebreak_locale:=0
  else XeTeX_linebreak_locale:=cur_name; {we ignore the area and extension!}
end
   which means I think that it's looking for a string not an integer and so 0 is "0" not 0

Comment: @DavidCarlisle indeed, `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale ""` has the same effect as not specifying any, so that seems to be the default case